# Basement Bathroom water ejector/sump pump running sporadically and bolts stripped

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, pump, sump-pump

Our basement bathroom has a water ejector/sump pump, as seen here : [Basement sump setup](https://imgur.com/a/oUtSQba)

I've heard it running every hour today and last night, yet no one has used it. We had a heavy rain on Monday but no water since. I went downstairs today to open the lid by removing the bolts and they snapped(heavily rusted). 2 questions:

1. Why does it keep running every hour and how would I test it?
2. Can I remove the old bolts and just use silicone bathroom caulking to reseal it? In the pictures in the link, I believe we have plumbers putty in place and it's cracked in a portion so the PVC pipe shakes and I imagine it isn't sealed. https://imgur.com/a/oUtSQba

Comment: Where is the PVC cracked? The sump likely cannot achieve proper siphoning due to unexpected air. You test it by dumping water in the pit.

Comment: It's cracked on the plumbers putty actually, here is an image and you can see the crack. https://imgur.com/gallery/CAIzgG5

Comment: In regards to the rusted out bolts/screws. Can I go ahead and remove the rest and just do a silicone caulking?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to remove the bolts or nuts to access the pit. The lid should be mechanically re-fastened after you are done so that no one accidentally falls in. It's no accident that you see 8 bolt holes around the lid. No, silicone is not a mechanical fastener. A small child falling in head first will have traumatic consequences.

Comment: How do I back out those rusted screws? Heads snapped off and while I haven't taken off the lid yet-the fact that these are so rusted makes me thinks there's an improper seal or no seal at all on the current setup-we didn't install.

Comment: Since this is really a sewer mascerator pit you do need an air tight seal.  You might be able to re-tap the existing holes one diameter larger to mechanically fasten or you silicon it and then install some metal strapping and just tap con that into the slab.

Comment: Try spraying some PB Penetrating Catalyst on them 2 or 3 times fifteen minutes apart. That stuff works wonders for car work. The ones which have snapped off will have to be drilled out. I'm not terribly surprised that they're snapping off considering that a sump pit is always damp. Feel free to curse at the installer who chose a rusting metal over something like stainless steel or brass.

Comment: Also, are you positive it's a sump pit? Have you traced where those pipes lead and confirmed that water is ejected? Radon mitigation lids looks quite similar.

Comment: I did confirm it's sump and mascerator pit-I got the PB penetrating catalyst and I got a couple of drill out kits but having a hell of a time figuring it all out :P. I shall curse away.

Comment: Any luck? Did the cursing help? 

Comment: Update: PB penetrating after 10 sprays over 5 hours did not loosen the remaining broken bolts-of the 8 bolts-all 8 broke off. I was unable to successfully backout those with the kits I bought after breaking some bits but was able to push the bolts out the other side of the sump basin lip. Added larger bolts-not all took, but added a new foam seal-caulking and tapped in new bolts/nuts to the lip of the basin. I've had 50 lbs of weight holding down the basin lid. Regarding the constant flow of water: yup, turned off the water to the toilet downstairs and it immediately stopped flowing.

Comment: Cont'd: Need to get a new flapper for the toilet which I may have a spare from the kit I bought awhile back.....house stuff never ends. Thank you all for your help-the cursing, smells and loss of one drill bit to the depths of hades will not stop me from learning this stuff.

Comment: Glad to hear you made things right and fixed your issue! Anytime I think "This task doesn't seem too difficult", the house always silently replies "Bless your heart"

Comment: Certainly feel free to self-answer your question as it may help others in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Running without use would make the first suspect be that the toilet (or other fixture, but the toilet is the usual one) is leaking, which you'd typically check for by shutting off the water supply to the toilet.

If the pump stops running and the toilet tank is down, without anybody flushing it, plain old common toilet leak.

As for the rusty bolts: Grind, drill, or whatever it takes to destructively remove the rusted bolts, and install 8 new stainless steel ones. Put some anti-seize compound on those for good measure.